# Android ListView CursorAdapter Alphabet initials

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, alphabetized

I want to implement Material Style ListView with CursorAdapter and Alphabet headers just like shown in the link below.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/67537/1095843/8h5VtFvLlRMOsqI/2015-08-19%20at%209.28%20AM.png

The Alphabet initials is just a textview in the layout_item of my listview. How can I determine when do I set the alphabet. It looks simple but since it is a cursor adapter, I see that when I scroll up and down, this textView value keeps on changing/disappearing. Please Note: I am using a cursor adapter so the data comes row by row. I do not have the liberty of sending all the data to the adapter at once to put everything into a map and index it. Has anyone done a similar thing? Is there a class in Java which I can use.

```
private String sectionName = "";
public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    if (!newSectionName.equals(sectionName)) {
        holder.txtSectionName.setText(newSectionName);
        sectionName = newSectionName;
    } else {
        holder.txtSectionName.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you should look into `RecyclerView` and the material design support library google came out with. Those 2 resources will get you started. The Scrolling bubble is essentially an onScroll event that takes the user's position and based on that (and the amount they scrolled) Goes over a set threshold of what letter to display in that bubble.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But I am not concerned about the scrolling bubble. I am talking about the Alphabet indexes on the left side.

Comment: that's easier actually. Using a recyclerview make sure you implement getItemViewType() and getItemViewTypeCount(). Then you now have 2 different kinds of views to display in your recyclerview. So when you populate your recyclerview check and see alphabetically when a letter change occurs. When it does occur, switch the views out to your other view with the letter to the left.

Comment: I think it is going to create the same issue as a normal listview. When I scroll up say from section B to A, It will show A on the left side for the last item in section A which I do not want. Let me know If I am not clear.

Comment: in that case, I'd have to question your design decision.. if I was a user that would be the functionality I expect.